# Python open() function not working in Spyder but working in the terminal with the same interpreter

Tags: python, file, spyder

Hi I am having some issues with trying to run a very simple program in Spyder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May 13 18:51:59 2017

@author: admin
"""

f = open('shark-species.txt')

for line in f:
    print(line)
```

The .txt file contains only letters from the latin alphabet. The error I am getting when running in spyder IPython or Python console is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-eccaeae0c773>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/admin/pybin/LCPWP/Chapter4/sharkspecies.py', 
    wdir='/Users/admin/pybin/LCPWP/Chapter4')

File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/admin/pybin/LCPWP/Chapter4/sharkspecies.py", line 11, in 
<module>
for line in f:

File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, 
in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 
7869: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now the weird thing is that the program runs just fine from the terminal and both Spyder and the terminal are using the same interpreter so I'm really struggling to see why Spyder is doing this. At the bootom of the screen in Spyder it also explicitly says coding is UTF-8.

Comment: That coding is for the *script*.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, however the .txt file is also utf-8 encoded and I am using Python 3.5.2 interpreter provided by Anaconda

Comment: So? What matters is whatever encoding the file is being opened with by default, not the encoding of the script.

Answer (score 2):

The file does contain Unicode characters, the preferred way to open files is it by using the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module as it follows:

```
 import codecs

 with codecs.open('file', 'r', 'utf-8') as fp:
      lines = fp.readlines()
```

Comment: Or the Python 2/3 compatible way: `io.open(...)`.

Comment: I think you mean codecs.open and yeah this works thanks but do you have any idea why the standar open function works in my terminal but not in spyder?

Comment: If you are using Python 3, no need for codecs because the builtin `open` has the same functionality.

Comment: hi I am using Python 3 and the builtin open function is not opening the file in spyder

Comment: @Someguy: It works on your terminal because it support utf-8. See:sys.getfilesystemencoding() in https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-names-command-line-arguments-and-environment-variables

Comment: It seems it's more of a matter of it failing in Spyder because it appears to expect the output of programs to be ascii and the output of your program is not.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, the default encoding that is being used in the Spyder terminals is not the same as your system terminal. Weird, but you can just pass `open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: But isn't it actually failing not at the file read itself which works as is, but at the printing which then spyder tries to read back in. In that sense, this answer doesn't seem quite right because the read works fine by default, there's no need to explicitly read the file as utf-8 in python 3.

Comment: @pvg  I'm not sure. The traceback seems to indicate is is failing when the file reads, i.e. `for line in f:`. Plus, I'm pretty sure it would be a `UnicodeEncodeError` isntead if the *terminal* didn't support utf8, which I'm pretty sure the terminal does.

Comment: Ah yeah maybe I'm not reading the trace right. Still leaves open the question how Spyder is making that read/decode default to something else, out of nowhere.

Comment: @pvg it is *very* weird, I've gotta say.

Comment: If your errors persist, please open an issue at Spyder Github repository: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder, I'm currently one of the project maintainers